# type issue when using reduce that adds keys in to an empty object typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have this function that reduces an object, my current issue is the I am using reduce on
to fill the values of acc[key] to be object[key];
both are erroring out, in code.. I don't want to use any type.

> acc[key]
> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
>
> object[key]
> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'

Playground Link
[Try](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAECUFMBMFcGNKgPICMBWl4BdQEkBbA2bAQ1QBskBCa0ANQCZRoB7AO11gGclsALJNEhVsSVgAdIAJ1LZW00AHd%20AS3j9Qq7qG4VWSgHQAoSAA8JC3PA7dc0mAkhpMOQsTKUkAXlAAeABVQczF2aB1WDCxsAD4AClJpaQAuXWxpVXYAcwBtAF0AGlBI9FSAgEpQbxjQAG9jUFAQUAJSAGskUl1%20Ugp9JVAbCQBPBsHbXBLoqrrQQ3mS0ABfAG4x5qzIXF6KYqicUA7h7jGbdjtDyGOZl2jDI%2044qZxytcbmgDNVCjFFB9ABHJQIkkOxWLhMgDBKAHARWAA3TpJUijRpnC5fH4yGAAaSuOl8D0MmN%20cTiR0q1VA1ES0kMmXgFFgwkeFNe6zA8AcclBkAGz1wSlUAlAJOx0Eux1OE1A7D5twOvjFDmgeOOhhVTjJpHg8CKFKqNXqjUaOvgOSOeRmAotVzybxNDmwsGk7GBuodSyKtSW7MaTpdbrlSgV2DWq2MxiAA)

```ts
// Reduce Object Immutable !! V2 dont use the delete operator which is slow.
export const reduceObjectImmutable = <T extends object>(
  arr: string[],
  obj: T
) => {
  // make a shallow copy
  const object = { ...obj };
  // get all object keys
  const keys = Object.keys(object);
  // filter keys that are not in the remove array
  const filteredKeys = keys.filter((key) => !arr.includes(key));
  // create new object with filtered keys
  const newObject = filteredKeys.reduce((acc, key) => {
    // Error on both...
    acc[key] = object[key];
    return acc;
  }, {});
  return newObject;
};
```

Comment: @Phil edit is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest against the `object` type here and using `Record<string, any>` instead. You need to then type your initial empty object on your reducer.

```
// Reduce Object Immutable !! V2 dont use the delete operator which is slow.
export const reduceObjectImmutable = <T extends Record<string, any>>(arr: string[], obj: T): Partial<T> => {
  // make a shallow copy
  const object = { ...obj };
  // get all object keys
  const keys = Object.keys(object);
  // filter keys that are not in the remove array
  const filteredKeys = keys.filter((key) => !arr.includes(key));
  // create new object with filtered keys
  const newObject = filteredKeys.reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc[key] = object[key];
    return acc;
  }, {} as Record<string, any>);
  return newObject as Partial<T>;
};
```

Comment: they say any is bad, but I think some times there is no other way right.

Comment: is there any way that it could be compatible with type of the inserted object what ever the inserted type is ?

Comment: I edited it to make the output type `Partial<T>`, which means that what comes out will be typed the same as what went in... except that some properties may not be present. I think that's what you want.

Comment: If you don't want to use `any` (or if you have rules in your tsconfig preventing it, you can use `unknown` instead. It is best to avoid it when possible, but in this case you're creating a generic handler so there's not a great way to get around it unless you want to do something like `Record<string, string  | number | boolean>` and you can really narrow down the possible values of your object to a manageable number of types.

Comment: the idea here I wanted the output to be compatible with my state. now every thing works.